# How to draw a map on android device?

Tags: navigation, android, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to display a map on android tablet. I have a gapping node which publishes a "map" topic. To display it I followed make_a_map tutorial from android apps, that can be found on rosjava github. Unfortunately instead of displaying a map, application crashes due to out of memory problem. What am I doing wrong? How can I access OccupancyGrid message and display its content on my tablet?

Map info taken from rostopic echo map_metadata:

resolution: 0.0500000007451
width: 4000
height: 4000

My tablet is Samsung Galaxy note 10.1 which has 2GB RAM, 1,4 GHz quad core CPU and runs on Android 4.1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94506/how-to-draw-a-map-on-android-device?/) by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-10-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2013-10-26**:
How large is your map? I suggest you edit your question to include the map metadata info (e.g. rostopic echo /map/info ) as well as maybe some details about what type of tablet you are displaying on. Out-of-memory issues might be completely reasonable with a large map and a low-memory device.

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2013-10-26**:
thank you for your comment. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to use a smaller map.  Android has some known limitations on texture size.  Here are some links to help you figure out what's the maximum for your device:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527695/how-an-i-find-the-maximum-texture-size-for-different-phones

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573178/limitation-on-texture-size-android-open-gl-es-2-0

The easiest workaround is to resize the map before drawing it.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2013-10-27**:
Yeah, map was too big. Problem disappeared. Thank you but right now it seems that it doesn't go into draw method and I have no idea why...

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-10-27**:
Please ask in another question and include source code so the new problem can be easily searched for.

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2013-10-27**:
Done. It's here: http://answers.ros.org/question/94946/why-occupancygridlayer-class-doesnt-access-draw-method/